# Atualizar ng-repeat quando receber valores do Firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

Olá!
Estou aprendendo agora a usar o Angularjs, mas ja sou programador experiente em Android.

Eu recebo corretamente os dados do firebase, mas o `ng-repeat` não atualiza quando o array é alterado. Se eu clicar em algum outro campo ele atualiza...

`javascript` que recebe os dados do `firebase`.

```
$scope.notas = [ ];

var retrieveNotas = function () {
    firebase.database().ref("notas").on('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function (child) {
            $scope.notas.push(child.val());
        });
        console.log($scope.notas)
    });
};
```

tabela com `ng-repeat`

```
<table class="table">
    <tr class="tdAlign" ng-show="notas.length > 0">
        <th></th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Cliente</th>
        <th>Valor</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tdAlign" ng-class="{selecionado: nota.selecionado}" ng-repeat="nota in notas | filter:busca">
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="nota.selecionado"></td>
        <td>{{nota.nome | uppercase}}</td>
        <td>{{nota.data}}</td>
        <td>{{nota.cliente.fantasia}}</td>
        <td>{{nota.valor | currency}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para atualizar a array de notas, você precisará rodar a função $apply do Angular.

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
  $scope.notas.push(child.val());
});
```